# Gulp and Babel - signal async completion error

Tags: node.js, gulp, babeljs

I'm new to Gulp and Babel otherwise I would say more regarding this problem. I believe I installed Babel correctly including:

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

However I currently get this error:

> The following tasks did not complete: scripts
>
> Did you forget to signal async completion?

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var babel = require("gulp-babel");

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src("app/js/app.js")
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/js"));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/js/app.js', 'scripts');
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('scripts', 'watch'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just pass the name of a task to `gulp.watch()`, you have to pass it a function. You can use `gulp.series()` or `gulp.parallel()` to generate one that simply calls the task it is given:

```
gulp.watch('app/js/app.js', gulp.series('scripts'));
```

Comment: I've shortened it to this: 

var gulp = require("gulp");

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    console.log('scripts');
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('scripts')); Still doesn't work.

Comment: That's completely different code and therefore a completely different problem. This time it doesn't work because you're not calling the callback function: `function(cb) { console.log('scripts'); cb(); }`

Comment: Also read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897877/gulp-error-the-following-tasks-did-not-complete-did-you-forget-to-signal-async/36899424#36899424)

Comment: Sorry, I got ahead of myself. I made the change you suggested and it didn't work. So I made additional changes but you're right, it's a different question.