# Signal async completion error although I returned a stream

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-4

I can't figure out why I'm getting

> Did you forget to signal async completion?

Here's my setup:

```
gulp.task('compile-ts', () => {
    return tsProject.src(config.files.src.ts)
        .pipe($.tap((file, t) => {
            logVerbose('Compiling "' + file.path + "'");
        }))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe($.typescript(tsProject))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe($.chmod(755))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist));
});

gulp.task('copy-assets', () => {
    return gulp.src(config.files.src.css_html_js, { base: config.src })
        .pipe($.tap((file, t) => {
            logVerbose('Copying "' + getFileName(file.path) + "'");
        }))
        .pipe($.chmod(755))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist));
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', (done) => {
    browserSync.init({
        "port": 3000,
        "startPath": "dist/index.html",
        "browser": "chrome",
        "logLevel": "silent",
        "server": {
            "middleware": {
                "0": null
            }
        }
    }, done);  
    process.on('exit', () => {
        browserSync.exit();
    });
})

gulp.task('watch', gulp.parallel(() => {
    gulp.watch(config.files.ts, gulp.series('compile-ts'));
}, () => {
    gulp.watch(config.files.css_html_js, gulp.series('copy-assets'));
}));

gulp.task('serve-dist', gulp.parallel('watch', 'browser-sync'));
```

According to the stacktrace, the offending line is

```
gulp.watch(config.files.ts, gulp.series('compile-ts'));
```

inside the `watch` task. The task `compile-ts` is working and it returns a stream, which should be enough to signal completion. But why am I getting the error anyway?

This is `gulp@4.0.0-alpha.2`.

EDIT:

Changing the `watch` task to

```
gulp.task('watch', (done) => {
    gulp.watch(config.files.css_html_js, gulp.series('copy-assets'));
    gulp.watch(config.files.ts, gulp.series('compile-ts'));
    done();
});
```

I don't get any errors anymore, but the task is finished within 4ms and does nothing at all. If I remove the `done` part, I get the same error again.

EDIT2: I split the tasks up some more to be able to pinpoint the problem,

```
gulp.task('watch-ts', () => {
    return gulp.watch(config.files.ts, gulp.series('compile-ts'));
});

gulp.task('watch-assets', () => {
    return gulp.watch(config.files.css_html_js, gulp.series('copy-assets'));
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.parallel('watch-ts', 'watch-assets'));
```

Now `watch-ts` and `watch-assets` both give me that error message. Either of which returns a stream as far as I can tell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gulp error: The following tasks did not complete: Did you forget to signal async completion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897877/gulp-error-the-following-tasks-did-not-complete-did-you-forget-to-signal-async)

Comment: Also doesn't `tsProject.src()` return a stream? [`gulp.watch()`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglobs-opts-fn) expects a string or an array of strings.

Comment: Corrected. Doesn't change the outcome though and have checked the proposed answer before posting my question as - in my opinion - I'm returning a stream (= your answer item 1.)

Comment: It does change the outcome. Your `watch` task is now correctly signaling async completion. Of course it's not going to do anything unless you modify one of the watched files (or use the `ignoreInitial` option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **always** need to signal async completion in **every** function that composes a task. Not just those that are asynchrounous. Not just those that use streams. If you're not returning a stream in a function, you still need to signal async completion somehow (usually by invoking a callback).

So your first edit was already correct:

```
gulp.task('watch', (done) => {
  gulp.watch(config.files.css_html_js, gulp.series('copy-assets'));
  gulp.watch(config.files.ts, gulp.series('compile-ts'));
  done();
});
```

Invoking the callback here makes sure that gulp knows that your `watch` task has completed successfully. "Completed successfully" in this case means that your task has started the two watches. Both watches will continue to run even after the `watch` job has finished. So there's nothing wrong with the fact that the `watch` task terminates after 4ms.

Starting a watch however does **not** automatically trigger the execution of the listener function. You'll have to modify one of the watched files first. Alternatively you can pass the [`ignoreInitial` option](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/API.md#opts) to `gulp.watch()` which will trigger the watch when it first starts up:

```
gulp.task('watch', (done) => {
  gulp.watch(config.files.css_html_js, {ignoreInitial:false}, gulp.series('copy-assets'));
  gulp.watch(config.files.ts, {ignoreInitial:false}, gulp.series('compile-ts'));
  done();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Sven, it's working now. I said it did nothing because it actually was doing nothing at all. If you look closely, you'll see that e.g. the `compile-ts` task refers to a glob var `config.files.src.ts`, compare this to the glob var from the watch and - lightning strikes. So actually the glob was undefined and the error message was misleading.