# gulp 4.0: run tasks in series

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-4

I'm trying to run a set of tasks in series, that is one after the other in Gulp 4.0 however when I add my 3rd task my gulp code breaks.

```
    gulp.task('concat-js', (done) => {
      gulp.src([  
        'app1.js',
        'app2.js',
      ])
      .pipe(concat("app.js")) 
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
      done();
    });

    gulp.task('concat-css', (done) => {
      gulp.src([
        '.styles1.css',
        '.style2.css'
      ])
      .pipe(concat("app.css"))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
      done();  
    });

    gulp.task('minify-js', (done) => {
      gulp.src('./build/app.js')
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
      done();
    })

    //this works & creates /build with the app.js & app.css files
    gulp.task('build-production-static-resource', gulp.series('concat-js', 'concat-css',, (done) => {
      done();
    }));
```

If I delete the build folder to start all over & try adding another task (minfy-js), my third task fails & the build folder also doesn't get created.

```
    //File not found with singular glob: /Users/user/myapp/build/app.js
    gulp.task('build-production-static-resource', gulp.series('concat-js', 'concat-css', 'minify-js', (done) => {
      done();
    }));
```

Answer (score 4):

The way you're signalling async completion of your tasks is wrong. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897877/gulp-error-the-following-tasks-did-not-complete-did-you-forget-to-signal-async/36899424#36899424) for an overview of the different ways in which you can signal async completion in gulp.

Basically all the streams that you create via `gulp.src()` are asynchronous. That means you create the stream and your code immediately returns. However the actual processing of the stream starts only *after* you exit the task function. In order for gulp to know that you're using a stream and that it has to wait for the stream to finish processing, you need to `return` the stream from your task.

You're doing something else entirely. You're invoking a callback function `done` which is another way to signal asynchronous task completion to gulp. However that's the completely wrong way in this case, because when you invoke the callback function `done` the stream you created hasn't even started to process.

That means gulp thinks your `concat-js` task has finished, although the code inside your task hasn't even really started running. So when the `minify-js` task runs your `./build/app.js` file hasn't been created yet. Boom. Error.

To fix this always `return` the streams from your tasks:

```
gulp.task('concat-js', () => {
  return gulp.src([  
      'app1.js',
      'app2.js',
    ])
    .pipe(concat("app.js")) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
});

gulp.task('concat-css', () => {
  return gulp.src([
      '.styles1.css',
      '.style2.css'
    ])
    .pipe(concat("app.css"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
});

gulp.task('minify-js', () => {
  return gulp.src('./build/app.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
})

gulp.task('build-production-static-resource', gulp.series(
  'concat-js', 'concat-css', 'minify-js'
));
```