# Terminate running (watch) process (gulp-4.0)

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-browser-sync

I've implemented a task to run a server and react (reload) on changes of my source files.

```
export function serveDev (gulp) {
  return () => {
    const bs = browserSync.create();
    const stream =  bs.init(config.browsersync.opts);
    gulp.watch(`${config.source}/components/**/*.js`, gulp.series('scripts'));
    gulp.watch(`${config.source}/js/**/*.js`, gulp.series('scripts'));
    gulp.watch(config.browsersync.watch).on('change', bs.reload);
    return stream;
  };
}
```

I'm using **gulp-4.0** and I'm running this task from the command line.

What's the correct implementation to terminate this task correctly when the user hits *CTRL+C*?

When I terminate this running task with the key-shortcut *CTRL+C* I get the following error:

```
The following tasks did not complete: serve, sync
Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

The task is working properly until the user hits *CTRL+C*. When the signal coming from *CTRL+C* reach the task the error described above is printed out. I would like to know how to catch or how to react properly on the termination signal coming from *CTRL+C*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gulp error: The following tasks did not complete: Did you forget to signal async completion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897877/gulp-error-the-following-tasks-did-not-complete-did-you-forget-to-signal-async)

Answer (score 1):

You can kill the background process on terminal with `pkill` command like:

```
pkill gulp
```