# Gulpfile.js fails to load after upgrading to VS2018 15.8.1

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-2017

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2018 15.8.1 (pro) my Gulpfile.js fails to load.

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Failed to run "C:\...\Gulpfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
gulp[37688]: src\node_contextify.cc:631: Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
 1: 00007FF6586E82F5 
 2: 00007FF6586C4156 
 3: 00007FF6586C4221 
 4: 00007FF65869A69A 
 5: 00007FF658CE5EB2 
 6: 00007FF658CE7008 
 7: 00007FF658CE636D 
 8: 00007FF658CE628B 
 9: 000002A6C5C041C1
```

Even the simplest Gulpfile.js fails to load:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('default', function () {
    // place code for your default task here
});
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution was:

1. First, upgrade gulp packages (in packages.json):

   ```
   "gulp": "3.9.1" > "gulp": "4.0.0"
   "gulp-sass": "3.2.1" > "gulp-sass": "4.0.1"
   "gulp-uglify": "3.0.0" > "gulp-uglify": "3.0.1"
   "gulp-rename": "1.3.0" > "gulp-rename": "1.4.0"
   ```
2. Second, switch from "run-sequence" to gulp.series (see https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/)
3. Finally, to make sure all my tasks signaled task completion (see [Gulp error: The following tasks did not complete: Did you forget to signal async completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897877/gulp-error-the-following-tasks-did-not-complete-did-you-forget-to-signal-async))

The VS community had a few related threads with solutions, neither of which solved my issue:

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/314581/gulpfilejs-fails-in-task-runner-in-visual-studio-2.html
- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/312584/update-158-broke-task-runner-gulpfile.html