# how can i solve this error 'The following tasks did not complete: default, Did you forget to signal async completion? '

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

this is my gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('default', function () {
});
```

I write `gulp` in my terminal
and response is..

```
[19:47:02] Using gulpfile D:\DEV64\LearningJS\gulpfile.js

[19:47:02] Starting 'default'...

[19:47:02] The following tasks did not complete: default

[19:47:02] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

what can i do?

Comment: have you tried logging to the console inside the task, just to see if it is being called? `console.log("Something")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Gulp 3.x you didn't need to signal completion. But from Gulp 4.x you need to do that.

Gulp automatically passes a callback function to your task as its first argument. Simple way in your case would be calling the callback.

```
gulp.task('default', function(done) {
  console.log("Started");
  done();
});
```

For more information You can check this question out: [Gulp error: The following tasks did not complete: Did you forget to signal async completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897877/gulp-error-the-following-tasks-did-not-complete-did-you-forget-to-signal-async)

Answer (score 4):

This works nicely for me.

```
gulp.task('default', async  function(){
  console.log("This is default task!");
});
```

You can also try this one.

```
gulp.task('default', async ()=>
 console.log('This is default task!')
);
```

Comment: My Friend, This makes no sense. `Async` function should have an `await` to wait for an asynchronous task.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather `await` is used to resolve a promise returned by any function marked as `async`, however it's not the only way to resolve a Promise. Anyway, gulp is already instructed that the function may return a promise and thus handles it appropriately behind scene. So no need for `await`

Comment: Where to write this piece of code?