# Cant able to minify the css code using gulp- ugly minify

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify

I am not able to compile my CSS code using Gulp uglifycss. Whenever I tried Im getting this error

" Starting 'css'...
[10:45:12] The following tasks did not complete: CSS
[10:45:12] Did you forget to signal async completion?"

here is my code

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglifycss = require('gulp-uglifycss');

gulp.task('css', function () {
  gulp.src('./assets/css/*.css')
    .pipe(uglifycss({
      "maxLineLen": 80,
      "uglyComments": true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897877/gulp-error-the-following-tasks-did-not-complete-did-you-forget-to-signal-async

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gulp error: The following tasks did not complete: Did you forget to signal async completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897877/gulp-error-the-following-tasks-did-not-complete-did-you-forget-to-signal-async)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to solve this issue.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
gulp.task('minify-css', function () {
    return gulp.src('./assets/css/*.css')
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```