# Light Gulp 4 task still throwing 'async completion' error

Tags: asynchronous, gulp, completion, gulp-4

I've not used Gulp before, so I'm not migrating an old gulpfile to Gulp 4. I'm just trying to get a few basic tasks set up. However, regardless of the method I use to signal async completion as well documented in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897877/gulp-error-the-following-tasks-did-not-complete-did-you-forget-to-signal-async/36899424#36899424) I still get the "Did you forget to signal async completion?" error.

```js
'use strict';

/*
=====
PLUGINS
=====
*/

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

// sass
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

// js
var concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');


/*
=====
TASKS
=====
*/

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./lib/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./lib/build'))
})

/*
=====
EXPORT TASKS
=====
*/

exports.sass = sass;
```

With this super barebones setup shouldn't it work? Doesn't `return gulp.src` return a stream? What am I missing?

Node 10.15.0,
Gulp CLI 2.2.0,
Gulp 4.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
// exports.sass = sass;

exports.sass = gulp.series('sass');
```

or

```
exports.sass = 'sass';
```

You are using the task version (`gulp.task`) so you need the quotes.

If you were using the function version (recommended):

```
function sass2 () {
  return gulp.src('./lib/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./lib/build'))
};
```

then

```
exports.sass = sass2;
```

works fine.  Note that you have a `var sass` already so you would have to name your `function sass2` to something other than just `sass` again of course.