# Gulp [4.0.2] hangs when async function is completed even though callback is completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a gulp task that's hanging after completion.

Running `--verbose` on my command tells me that it completed the run, but it doesnt exit the process

```
// ./gulpfile.js/precon/index.js

const { preconMoveFile, preconExcelToMysql } = require('../../src/lib/preCon')

module.exports = async done => {
  try {
    await preconMoveFile()
    await preconExcelToMysql()
    done()
    // return <-- doesnt work either per comment
  } catch (e) {
    throw e
  }
}
```

below is the command line output, pardon my debug log output

```
C:\Users\ALilland\Documents\macros\experiments\forecast-scraper>set NODE_ENV=development& gulp precon --verbose
[12:33:57] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\macros\experiments\forecast-scraper\gulpfile.js
[12:33:57] Starting 'precon'...
[2019-07-30T19:33:57.264Z] DEBUG - [preCon.preconMoveFile] existing ./src/tmp/precon.xlsx removed
[2019-07-30T19:33:57.333Z] DEBUG - [preCon.preconMoveFile] copied new file to ./src/tmp/precon.xlsx
[2019-07-30T19:33:58.965Z]  INFO - [initialize.db.caePreconForecast] created caePreconForecast
[2019-07-30T19:33:59.012Z] DEBUG - [preCon.preconExcelToMysql] added rows to db
[12:34:00] Finished 'precon' after 3.24 s
```

I tried several of the options shown in the [docs](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion) with no success, and also tried several of the options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897877/gulp-error-the-following-tasks-did-not-complete-did-you-forget-to-signal-async) with no success

I have also tried calling `process.exit(0)` but that produces the `Did you forget to signal async completion?` warning that the docs mention

Edit:

I should also note my root index.js file that requires the `precon` task

```
// ./gulpfile.js/index.js

exports.default = require('./default')
exports.precon = require('./precon')
```

Comment: Try to return something after your last function/operation/call

Comment: @NullDev unsuccessful 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hang does not result from gulp, there is a background process still running preventing gulp from closing

the culprit was an open mysql pool connection

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const params = require('../config/mysql')

const db = mysql.createPool(params)

db.end() // <-- running this after each task resolves the issue
```