# Problem with gulp watch after upgrading to gulp 4

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

Linked to this issue = [Gulp error: The following tasks did not complete: Did you forget to signal async completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897877/gulp-error-the-following-tasks-did-not-complete-did-you-forget-to-signal-async)

When I try to run "watch" with the following code it errors:

```
gulp.task('watch', async function() {
    var watchJs = gulp.watch(paths.js, ['scripts']),
        watchJson = gulp.watch(paths.json, ['json']),
        watchHtml = gulp.watch(paths.html, ['html']),
        watchCss = gulp.watch(paths.css, ['css']),
        watchFonts = gulp.watch(paths.fonts, ['fonts']),
        watchAssets = gulp.watch(paths.assets, ['assets']),

        onChanged = function(event) {
            console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + '. Running tasks...');
        }

    watchJs.on('change', onChanged);
    watchJson.on('change', onChanged);
    watchHtml.on('change', onChanged);
    watchCss.on('change', onChanged);
    watchFonts.on('change', onChanged);
    watchAssets.on('change', onChanged);
});
```

Error says: `Error: watching src/js/**/*.js: watch task has to be a function (optionally generated by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)`

But I have no idea how to approach this. I tried putting the async on gulp.task('watch', async function() { but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 var watchJs = gulp.watch(paths.js, ['scripts']),  // gulp v3 syntax
```

to

```
 var watchJs = gulp.watch(paths.js, gulp.serie('scripts')),  //  gulp v4 syntax
```

and your others like that.  Find a migration guide for going from gulp v3 to v4.