# "Did you forget to signal async completion?"

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I am receiving the error message: *"The following tasks did not complete: default, sass. Did you forget to signal async completion?"* I am new to Gulp and trying to figure out what the mistake is. I believe it's something with my syntax, but as I am new to Gulp, I can't quite pinpoint it. Below are the contents of my gulpfile. Thank you in advance.

```
use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src('./assets/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../style.css'));
});


gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass', function() { 
    return gulp.watch('./assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
}));
```

Comment: `return gulp.src.....` Search with that error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gulp error: The following tasks did not complete: Did you forget to signal async completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897877/gulp-error-the-following-tasks-did-not-complete-did-you-forget-to-signal-async)