# Async completion error when function called, or callback not a function when called on default function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, gulp

I'm trying to make a function which calls some other functions :

```
copy = () => {
    copyHtml();
    copyCss();
    copyJs();
    copyImg();
}
exports.copy = copy;
```

Using `gulp copy`, the function works but I get this error :

> The following tasks did not complete: copy.
> Did you forget to signal async completion?

I'm not used to it and after searching I just changed my function like below, it works without error :

```
copy = (done) => {
    copyHtml();
    copyCss();
    copyJs();
    copyImg();
    done();
}
exports.copy = copy;
```

Then I added it to my default function :

```
defaultFunction = () => {
    copy();
    browsersyncServe();
}
exports.default = defaultFunction;
```

My problem is when I call the default function with gulp :

> done is not a function

If I directly call `copyHtml`, `copyCss`, `copyJs` and `copyImg` in the default function, it works and I get no error.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your functions run synchronously, without returning anything. While this works in early versions of gulp, currently [it no longer supports synchronous functions](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion/#no-synchronous-tasks). Now you need to use a callback (like in your question), or return a stream, promise, event emitter, child process, or observable (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36899424 for some implementations).

For your case, there are a bunch of things that could work, but here are three possibilities:

#### Using `async` Functions

Because gulp [supports promises](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion#returning-a-promise), you can just [make all of your functions async](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion/#using-asyncawait). You can call these functions like synchronous functions (since they are really synchronous under the hood):

```
copy = async () => {
    copyHtml();
    copyCss();
    copyJs();
    copyImg();
}
defaultFunction = async () => {
    // the await isn't strictly necessary, since copy is actually
    // synchronous, but it's probably good practice to use await,
    // if copy ever becomes asynchronous
    await copy(); 
    browsersyncServe();
}
exports.copy = copy;
exports.default = defaultFunction;
```

#### Returning a Promise

In the same vein, you can return a resolved promise (like `Promise.resolve()`) for any synchronous function gulp uses. Like the above example, this doesn't interfere with the synchronous invocation of these functions (as long as the returned value is ignored):

```
copy = () => {
    copyHtml();
    copyCss();
    copyJs();
    copyImg();
    return Promise.resolve();
}
defaultFunction = () => {
    copy();
    browsersyncServe();
    return Promise.resolve();
}
exports.copy = copy;
exports.default = defaultFunction;
```

#### Wrapping callback functions

Another possibility is to wrap your synchronous functions to become asynchronous. For example, using the asynchronous callback format would look something like this:

```
function wrapSyncToAsync(fn) {
    return function (done) {
        fn();
        done();
    };
}
copy = () => {
    copyHtml();
    copyCss();
    copyJs();
    copyImg();
}
defaultFunction = () => {
    copy();
    browsersyncServe();
}
exports.copy = wrapSyncToAsync(copy);
exports.default = wrapSyncToAsync(defaultFunction);
```

Here `copy` is your synchronous version that you can call via just `copy()`, while `exports.copy` is what gulp will call with a callback, e.g. `exports.copy(callbackFunction)`.

You can use `wrapSyncToAsync` to convert synchronous functions (that don't have any arguments) to asynchronous functions.

Answer (score 2):

The `copy` function needs a callback in its parameter, but you call it without parameter in `defaultFunction`, which will be undefined. That's why it complains "done is not a function".

Looks like all your functions are synchronized, `done` is no use. So you can just pass a dummy function to `copy`:

```
// the defaultFunction should call the done callback on finish as well
defaultFunction = (done) => {
    copy(() => {});
    browsersyncServe();
    done();
}
exports.default = defaultFunction;
```

BTW, a better way to perform actions one by one in the gulp task is to use the `series` to [compose](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks/#compose-tasks) the functions, and each of the function to be composed need to accept a callback function:

```
const { series } = require('gulp');

function copyHtml(done) {
  // .....
  done();  // callback when it is done
}

copy = series(
    copyHtml,
    copyCss,
    copyJs,
    copyImg
);

exports.copy = copy;
```

```
exports.default = series(copy, browsersyncServe);
```

Comment: Instead of passing a dummy function, shouldn't you use `copy(() => { browsersyncServe(); done(); })`? Maybe even with nodeback-style error propagation?

Answer (score 0):

When you call this :

```
defaultFunction = () => {
    copy();
    browsersyncServe();
}
exports.default = defaultFunction;
```

you are calling `copy()` without any arguments. Hence here:

```
copy = (done) => {
    copyHtml();
    copyCss();
    copyJs();
    copyImg();
    done();
}
exports.copy = copy;
```

`done` is not defined right. That is the error.

You can pass `done`:

```
defaultFunction = (done) => {
    copy(done);
    browsersyncServe();
}
exports.default = defaultFunction;
```

Comment: If copy needs a `done` callback because it's asynchronous, then `browsersyncServe` should not be called immediately after it

Comment: @Bergi Can you please explain me why it shouldn't ?

Comment: @Cédric, you're supposed to call `done` only when the task is completed. Calling it before `browsersyncServe` starts or is completed might cause unintended behavior.